# Bulk exif tags bat script not working peoperly

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, exiftool

I have a batch script to set `XMP:Subject` Exif tags on pictures in bulk.

`tags.txt` has all links of the pages and the tags. Links and Tags are separated by `=`.

This script should divide the URL and Tags divided by `=` remove the `https://www.` and all forward slashe `/` from it. And it will find a folder with this name.

Next, it should take the 2nd half of the `tags.txt` line, after `=`, and set that as `XMP:Subject` using `exiftool` on all jpg images.

Then it should go back and read the next line in `tags.txt`, which has different link and different tags.

but the problem is, its taking the tags from the 1st line in `tags.txt` and applying that to all images in all folders. Then it is taking the 2nd line tags, and setting these on all images in all folders.

Can someone please help me fix this issue?

```
:: bat file
:: V 4.0
@ECHO off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set batpath=%~dp0


echo.>"!batpath!\log.txt"

For /F "usebackq tokens=1,2  delims==" %%a in (tags.txt) Do (
  set link=%%a
  set tags=%%b

for /f %%h in ('type weblinks.txt') do (
    set link=%%h


set foldername=!link:https://www.=!
set foldername=!foldername:/=!

cd /d !foldername!


for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b *.jpg') do ( 

    
    set imagename=%%G
    rem echo "!imagename!"
    set imagenameonly=%%~nG
    set extn=%%~xG


"!batpath!\exiftool" -XMP:Subject="!tags!" "!imagenameonly!!extn!"

echo. ----------------------- !foldername!\!imagenameonly!!extn! ----->>"!batpath!\log.txt"
"!batpath!\exiftool" -XMP:Subject -a "!imagenameonly!!extn!" >>"!batpath!\log.txt"

    )

    del *.*_original

cd /d !batpath!


)
)
```

Comment: Plz, edit and add tags.txt file content/layout

Comment: [cross-site duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152975/interleave-files-with-cmd-using-echo/48153523#48153523)